# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java

I created this simple example which is used to read Linux uptime:

```
public String getMachineUptime() throws IOException {
    String[] dic = readData().split(" ");

    long s = (long) Array.get(dic, 1);
    return calculateTime(s);
}

private String readData() throws IOException {
    byte[] fileBytes;
    File myFile = new File("/proc/uptime");
    if (myFile.exists()) {
        try {
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(myFile.toPath());
        } catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException e) {
            return null;
        }

        if (fileBytes.length > 0) {
            return new String(fileBytes);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private String calculateTime(long seconds) {
    int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);
    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds)
            - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(day);
    long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds)
            - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(day)
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds)
            - TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(day)
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours)
            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minute);

    return "Day " + day + " Hour " + hours + " Minute " + minute
            + " Seconds " + second;
}
```

When I run the code I get this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Is there any other way to convert the result?

Comment: this line .long s = (long) Array.get(dic, 1);

Comment: Can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 13):

I believe you have to replace

```
long s = (long) Array.get(dic, 1);
```

with

```
long s = Long.valueOf((String) Array.get(dic, 1));
```

or even better:

```
long s = Long.valueOf(dic[1]);
```

The reason is that your array consists of `String` object, and *direct* casting won't work.

Comment: I get this no suitable method found for valueOf(Object)
    method Long.valueOf(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to String)
    method Long.valueOf(long) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to long)

Comment: Now I get this message java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "634618.11

Comment: Well...this means it's not `long` but `double`. :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be in the following line:

```
long s = (long) Array.get(dic, 1);
```

1. The get(Object array, int index) method of java.lang.reflect.Array returns an instance of Object, which cannot be directly cast to long.
2. You can access the element of the array simply by dic[1] instead of Array.get(dic, 1)

Replace with the following code:

```
long s = Long.parseLong(dic[1]);
```